# Next.js custom App getInitialProps TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have quite a simple app with Next JS starter kit and I am trying to get it work with custom app as specified on the [docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app):

```
class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {};
    const isAuthenticated = await (process.browser
      ? Auth0Client.clientAuth()
      : Auth0Client.serverAuth(ctx.req));

    console.log("isAuthenticated: ", isAuthenticated);

    if (Component.getInitialProps) pageProps = await App.getInitialProps(ctx);

    const auth = { isAuthenticated };
    return { pageProps, auth };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component } = this.props;
    return <Component auth={this.props.auth} />;
  }
}
```

It is placed inside _app.js of pages folder.

The thing is that my index page also has static

```
static async getInitialProps
```

and it triggers the following error for some reason:

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t6tA.png)

You can see my _app.js file here by this URL:
https://github.com/bodrovphone/next-app/blob/breakingPoint/pages/_app.js

And index.js file URL here:
https://github.com/bodrovphone/next-app/blob/breakingPoint/pages/index.js

Steps to reproduce:

1. clone the project [at this branch](https://github.com/bodrovphone/next-app/tree/breakingPoint)
2. npm install
3. npm run dev
4. navigate to localhost:3000

I would appreciate any assistance!

Comment: I've added a suggestion below, which I think solves your issue. If that's true, mark the answer as correct in case anyone else falls in the same situation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the respective `Component`'s `getInitialProps` each time, and not the `App`'s.

Change your **_app.js** following line:

```js
if (Component.getInitialProps) pageProps = await App.getInitialProps(ctx);
```

to

```js
if (Component.getInitialProps) pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Michails!. I have got to this idea right after posted this question. Would be great to update official Next.js documentation as there App used and it is quite confusing.